# Blocking current from Backup battery (3x1.5V=4.5V) when powerbank (5V) is turned on my timer switch

Tags: power, mosfet, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, powerbanks

I'd like to power cycle a RaspberryPi0 each 1h. I plan to use a TPl5110 for this, which can be powered by around 2.5-5.5V. I want to deliver 5V to the Vdd-Pin using a powerbank. However, once the RPI0 sends the done signal to the TPL5110-IC, too little current (<50mA) is drawn from the powerbank, which shuts the powerbank off.

Thus, I am thinking of using a Backup-Battery with 3x1.5V AA (alkaline) batteries to keep the TPL5110 powered on all the time.

Will it work as simple as adding a standard silicon diode after the 3x1.5V backup batteries, as sketched here:
[image]

I want to avoid current flowing from the backup battery to the RPI0 if it is powered on (at least as much as possible to avoid draining the backup battery low).

EDIT: my requirements are different from this question: [how to switch to backup battery when power fail?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/430588/how-to-switch-to-backup-battery-when-power-fail) since I do not just want to use a diode with forward voltage drop all the time since it consumes too much power for my application.
Thank you!

Comment: Add another diode in series with the power bank to prevent the AAs backfeeding

Comment: @TomCarpenter this seems a good option, the RPI0 can be powered up down to almost 3.3V: https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-zero/raspberry-pi-zero-hardware-general-specifications So you suggest a diode right after the powerbank. That will stop the AA from backfeeding but how much current is drawn from the AAs when the switch is turned on?

Comment: This question is asked over and over again. Does this one help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405188/5v-power-switcher-uninterruptable-power-source?rq=1

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thank you, that brought me one step further, I'll need an o-ring controller, as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otMKgwCxVyA with low-forward voltage drop and low reverse current. I'll see if I can find some suitable ICs for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just the circuit for you, here: [What does this MOSFET do in this voltage regulation circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/551195/what-does-this-mosfet-do-in-this-voltage-regulation-circuit/551196#551196)

This circuit uses a P-MOSFET and a diode and does exactly that function, with a bonus of little or no voltage drop when the battery is powering the circuit.

Use the P-MOSFET side on the AA side, and a Schottky diode on the power bank side.

Comment: thank you, I think I see what you were doing there and it perfectly fits my needs, just a few questions: 1) why do you need the 2nd 1k pull-down resistor (the 10k is clear to me to make the backup battery conducting, 2) Can you suggest widely used P-MOSFETs and schottky diodes, I can e.g. use 5V USB supply and just 3V 2xAA batteries, 3) When USB is shut off, isn't there some trickle charging of the AAs into the Powerbank over the Schottky diode, is that negligible?

Comment: The 1k is there to simulate a load. Without it you can’t visualize what the currents are doing. It’s not actually necessary in the circuit. As for the MOSFET choice choose one that has enough current capability for the load, and has a switching threshold for logic. The Schottky diode can be one that is designed for a power supply.

Comment: I have difficulties finding a P-MOSFET with gate threshold voltage as low ad 0.5V for 3AAAs but 2AA will also do and eventually there are 2V threshold P MOSFETS